# How define the norm of $v+W$

Tags: functional-analysis, definition, normed-spaces

I'm trying to solve the following exercise:

> Let $V$ be a normed linear space and let $W$ be a finite dimensional subspace of $V$. Show that, for all $v\in V$, there exists $w\in W$ such that $\|v+W\|=\|v+w\|$.

But I don't know how to deal with the $\|v+W\|$. It's well knowed that $$d(v,W)=\inf_{w\in W}\|v-w\|.$$ Is that ok define $$\|v+W\|=\inf_{w\in W}\|v+w\|,$$ or I'm wrong? Maybe use a $\sup$?

Comment: You want to find a $w \in W$ such that the infimum is actually attained.

Comment: I think you have the correct idea.  In other words, I think you're meant to define
$$
\|v + W\| := d(0,v+W).
$$
Since $W$ is a subspace, this is going to be the same as $d(v,W)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the usual definition of $\lVert v+W\rVert$ is $\inf\{\|v+w\|\mid w\in W\}$. So, the problem consists in proving that this infimum is actually a minimum, *under the assumption that $W$ is finite dimensional* (the assertion is false in general).